# Pytest setup and teardown functions - same as self written functions?

Tags: python, pytest

In the following example from pytest documentation:

[image]

The function `setup_function` is supposed to setup some data for some other function, say `test_data`. So If i write the function `test_data` i will have to invoke `setup_function` like this:

```
def test_data():
    setup_function(....)
    <Test logic here>
    teardown_function(....)
```

So the only difference is name convention ?

I don't understand how exactly is helps me creating setup data. I could have written the same code like this:

```
def test_data():
    my_own_setup_function(....)
    <Test logic here>
    my_own_teardown_function(....)
```

Since there is no way to tell pytest to automatically link a setup function to the test function it creates the setup data for - the parameter `function` of the function `setup_function` doesn't really help me if i don't need a function pointer.... so why bother creating name conventions for no reason?

From what i understand, the setup function parameter `function` only helps me if i need to use a function pointer - something i rarely need.

Comment: The point is they run before and after All your test do you only set them once and use them a lo of times they are like beforeall and after in other testing suites

Comment: But how do you link a certain setup_function to a certain test function and how do you make pytest treat it as a setup function and not as a test function ? What is the naming convention for it ?

And what's the naming convention `setup_function` for - i can write `some_name` function and it's the same...

Comment: Ifit starts with test_ it is a test setuo and teardown are understood by pytest automqtically so you dont have to write your own

Comment: Hard to believe pytest is so primitive that it can't link a specific setup function to a specific test function.

Comment: You DONT HAVE TO INVOKE THEM IN YOUR TESTS. They get invoked automqtically maybe thats what got you Wondering. If you Want a specific one for your specific test you write it with your custom name and INVOKE them in the test

Comment: Isn't there an annotation with '@pytest' that can be written just above the setup function in order to link it to a specific test WITHOUT invoking ANYTHING inside the tests ?

Something like `@pytest.link('test_function_2')`  written above the setup_function or tear down ? And then `test_function_2` will autimatically be executed right after its specific setup and before its specific teardown ?

I know there is no `link` option, just to demonstrate

Comment: Test_whstever Will Always execute first setup then the code inside it. If you Want to add specific setup you could write a custom function and decorate your test with it which is synctactic sugaring for what you are trying iirc

Answer (score 15):

If you want to setup specifics for a test or tests you can use a "normal" pytext fixture.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def setup_and_teardown_for_stuff():
    print("\nsetting up")
    yield
    print("\ntearing down")

def test_stuff(setup_and_teardown_for_stuff):
    assert 1 == 2
```

The thing to remember is that everyting before the yield is run before the test and everything after the yield is run after the test.

```
tests/unit/test_test.py::test_stuff 
setting up
FAILED
tearing down
```

Comment: that's a very cool tip, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

**Answer**

It appears that your question boils down to: What is the purpose/benefit of the `setup_function` and `teardown_function` as described in the [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html#method-and-function-level-setup-teardown)?

The benefit of using these functions is that you do not have to invoke them; both `setup_function` and `teardown_function` will automatically run before and after (respectively) each test.

To your point about having to pass a function pointer, this is not required in pytest>=3.0.  From the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html#method-and-function-level-setup-teardown):

> As of pytest-3.0, the function parameter is optional.

So you don't need to pass a function pointer to the `setup_function` and `teardown_function` functions; you can simply add them to a test file as described in the example below and they will be executed.

---

**Example**

For example, if you have a `test_setup_teardown.py` file that looks like:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def setup_function():
    print('setting up')


def test_1():
    print('test 1')
    assert 1 == 2


def teardown_function():
    print('tearing down')
```

and you run that file using pytest (something like `pytest test_setup_teardown.py`), pytest will output:

```
---- Captured stdout setup ----
setting up
---- Captured stdout call ----
test 1
---- Captured stdout teardown ----
tearing down
```

In other words, pytest automatically calls the `setup_function`, then runs the test (which fails), and then runs the `teardown_function`. The benefit of these functions is being able to specify what happens before and after all tests are run.

Comment: i think is call for the first function "setup_method"