# How do I run an async background task during async pytest?

Tags: python, multithreading, async-await, pytest, python-asyncio

I want to test interactions between a server `MyServer` and client `MyClient` using pytest. The server is async, and has an async `start()` method. Here is my setup:

```py
import pytest
from .server import MyServer
from .client import MyClient

PORT = 8765
HOST = "127.0.0.1"

async def run_server():
    await MyServer().start(host=HOST, port=PORT)

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    return MyClient(host=HOST, port=PORT)

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_can_get_response(client):
    response = await client.call_server()
    assert response is not None
```

I need the server to be booted up and run in the background when the tests run. There is a very simple solution here: before running pytest, just run a python file that calls `run_server()`, but it would be neater if I could boot up the server in this test file, so the server gets destroyed at the end.

My first instinct is to use threading:

```py
from threading import Thread

Thread(target=run_server).start()
```

However, the tests get run before the thread has time to start:

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<run_server() running at /path/to/file> wait_for=<_GatheringFuture pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x105fc90a0>()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
```

Adding a `time.sleep()` so the server has time to boot doesn't make a difference, the tests run immediately.

I believe another alternative is to use a fixture, i.e. booting up the server for the course of each test. I attempted the following:

```py
@pytest.fixture
async def run_server():
    await MyServer().start(host=HOST, port=PORT)

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    return MyClient(host=HOST, port=PORT)

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_can_get_response(client, run_server):
    await run_server # Not run_server() because the fixture is already a coroutine
    response = await client.call_server()
    assert response is not None
```

This boots up the server as expected, but not in the background: `MyServer().start()` runs forever and blocks the tests from running.

How can I start my server in the background and run it over the course of the tests?

Comment: I don't know how your classes are made, but you could run your server as a Future object. `asyncio.create_task(MyServer().start(host=HOST, port=PORT))`

Comment: You could use setup/teardown : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984719/pytest-setup-and-teardown-functions-same-as-self-written-functions

Comment: @DevangSanghani putting the above run_server in setup_function requires an async def, and the tests run before it executes.

Comment: @user56700 Pytest's event loop exists only within each function. If I add the task to that event loop, it gets added at the end, and doesn't start until after the test. If I asyncio.wait() that task, the tests run immediately. If I create a new event loop outside the tests, the tests are then blocked and do not run.

Comment: @Student cant you just run it in the event loop then? Like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270681/can-an-asyncio-event-loop-run-in-the-background-without-suspending-the-python-in - send loop to the function and wrap it.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of the root `pytest` folder add the following to [`conftest.py`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files):

```py
import asyncio

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 8888

async def start():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        # await server start here.
    except
        # await server stop here.
    finally:
        loop.close()
        
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def event_loop():
    return asyncio.get_event_loop()

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
def server(event_loop):
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(start(), loop=event_loop)

    # Sleeps to allow the server boot-up.
    event_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(1))

    try:
        yield
    finally:
        task.cancel()
```

The [session scope](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#fixture-scopes) ensures the same server instance is live until all tests run (as opposed to restarting on each individual test). Then in your tests, you can query the server;

```py
import asyncio
import pytest

from .conftest import HOST, PORT

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_http_request():
    # You can use anything to query the server - httpx, aiohttp, etc.
    # Using native code for the sake of example.

    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(HOST, PORT)
    writer.write(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n")
    data = await reader.read(1024)
    assert data.startswith(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n")
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()
```

The benefit of this solution is that coverage tools - like [`pytest-cov`](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#usage) - will count all of the areas within your server code that is being tested. I used the above solution for a personal project, [`mitm`](https://github.com/synchronizing/mitm/tree/master/tests), that uses `asyncio.start_server`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Process instead of Thread. Here's an example (not full code, just to illustrate):

```py
import pytest
from multiprocessing import Process

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_http_file_upload():
    httpd = http_server.build_server(host, port)
    Process(target=httpd.serve_forever, args=(), daemon=True).start()
    await transfer_file(file, f"http://{host}:{port}{remote_path}")
    ...
```

Process will also terminate itself at the end of test.